# How to post data two times in a row with html forms and php

Tags: php, html, forms, post, upload

I have a page where I'll be able to upload images to my website's gallery. Before I got this problem it worked perfectly fine to upload **one** image to the gallery, including a description. I've used a html form to make the upload-page and PHP to both upload the image to the server and import the data to the database. The gallery is then shown depending if there's image-data  in my database.

So this method worked just fine. Now I wanted to post multiple images at once which made it a bit harder because now I need textareas for every image that I include to the upload process. For this I had to make another step in the upload process, another page.

**First page:** Gather the images-data in a html-form, no problems here. I can echo out all the data on the next page if I'd like.

**Second page:** Get the data from the first page and write out the code for the textareas depending on how many images that were included. This works and I can echo out the descriptions on the next page as an array. Each image should have a description. So I use another form for this because I need to gather the descriptions aswell.

```
    <form action='add4.php' method='post'       enctype='multipart/form-data'> 
<?php   $imgcount = count($_FILES['filename']['name']);

            for($a=0;$a<$imgcount;$a++) {
                    echo            "<label for='text'>Beskrivning av bilden " .$_FILES['filename']['name'][$a]. ":</label><br />           <textarea rows='5' cols='40' name='description[]' multiple='multiple' id='description'></textarea><br /><br />";        } ?>


    <input type='hidden' name='filename[]' value='No idea what to write here!' multiple='multiple'>
    <label for='password'>Lösenord:*</label><br />
    <input type='password' name='password' id='password' required><br />
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload files' id='submit'><br /><br />
    <label>* Required fields</label>
    </form>
```

**Third page:** Get the images-data **and** the descriptions for each of them. This page is however not 100% done yet. I can write the descriptions out but not the image data, because I do not know how to send them through the form a second time. I tried to use print_r but apparently it didn't keep it as an array this way so now I'm out of ideas.

I know some javascript if that's necessary but no jQuery.

**How can I keep all the image data from the first page to the last page?** Please keep in mind that I'm still a newbie. Wouldn't be to surprised if the problem was super easy to solve... ;)

---

**EDIT:**

So today I tried to use cookies for this and it kind of worked. I could use print_r($_COOKIE) and get the whole array printed out on the last page. But when I tried to write out a specific value with echo it didn't really work... I've looked around for a solution but didn't find anything. **What's the syntax for $_COOKIE[] when I'm using multi-dimensional arrays?**

I've tried to write like these examples:

```
echo $_COOKIE['filename']['name'][0];
echo $_COOKIE[['filename']['name'][0]];
```

etc...

Comment: What is your intention with the images ultimately. To save them to the filesystem ?

Comment: @lagbox They will end up on the server permanent.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this would work but try saving it in a cookie, so then on the last page it gets it back.

Comment: Hmm okay, I will try to look into that. Thing is, I'm learning as I'm searching for solutions. I have, for example, never used cookies. I've seen that one could use a session as well, not so sure how though. Thanks for the advise! :)

Answer (score 1):

After the **first** form is submitted:

My suggestion is to save the upload files to the filesystem. Add those filenames to the db. 
You can then iterate over those images to add them to the next page for reference and add textfields for each image. Assign these text fields a name like `imagetext[$img_id]`

After the **second** form is submitted:

You can update the image records with their descriptions by using the ids that you are passing through the form. The ids are the keys of $_POST['imagetext'] array.

Just one way to remove that problem.

Comment: I've thought about this too, could be a good idea. But what if the final step where I send all the data to the database fails? Then I have to either delete the files manually, have images that I don't use on the website at all or manually write all the data to my database. But I guess this is just a problem for me, because I'm sure there's a way to delete the uploaded files if something goes wrong with the database sync. :P

Comment: the images are saved, they are fine .. if there is an error you can just display the second form again to try again